# What is the proper approach to modern UI for Windows Desktop Apps?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, winapi, user-interface, mfc

I have an existing app with an extensive C++ model that I would like to hook up to a nice, modern Windows 7 or 8 UI.  The current (ancient) UI for our app was developed in the early Windows XP / 95/98 era using pure Win32 API.  Our code is currently compiling / linking through Visual Studio 2010.

It seems there's a lot of different development API "standards" on Windows:  Win32, MFC, ATL, COM and .NET.  Over the past 14 years, my engineers have pretty much towed the Microsoft line:  in 2001, it was "MFC is dead — we must move to ATL" (we didn't).  Then ".NET will REPLACE MFC" (it doesn't appear to have).

So now we're ready to dump our old UI code.  It would be nice to work with a set of standards that are solid and efficient, but also one we could create UI with quickly.  Putting aside QT ( on which I've read a lot of well-argued pluses and minuses here on stackoverflow):

1)  Would the modern UI development approach for Windows 7 & 8 be to use MFC or .NET?

2)  For a .NET approach (assuming there's solid reasons for choosing .NET) could we use our C++ model code UNMANAGED with a .NET app?

3)  Is it essential to do development in Visual Studio 2012, even if our app would not initially be design for a Metro appearance?

4)  Are there any other Microsoft toolkits that should be considered for desktop app development?

Stephen

Answer (score 4):

1. You could go with either approach.  However, .NET is much more common for user interface design, and has many advantages (in terms of quicker development) if you need a flexible user interface.
2. Yes.  C++/CLI works well to bridge native code with the .NET user interface.
3. No.  You can do this in VS2010.  That being said, VS 2012 does have many advantages, especially when working with C++.  The upgrade would likely be beneficial.
4. I would look at [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx).  The new Windows 8 user interface could be interesting, but might be difficult to use with your previous code base.  Also, it will not work on older operating systems.  In my experience, WPF is the best, currently improving option (there were many improvements in .NET 4.5) which supports mixing an existing code base with new user interface technologies.

Comment: Would .NET typically be combined with Windows Forms?  And if so, the underlying code is C#, right?

Comment: @SMGreenfield You can use .NET with WinForms - though, as I said, today, I'd use WPF.  You'd typically write the "view logic" in C# (or VB, but if you're a C++ dev, C# would be more comfortable), then integrate with your C++ logic below that.  This is the approach Visual Studio uses since VS2010, btw (it's WPF front end, with a lot of legacy native code underneath)

Answer (score 4):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430571/11449) answer I gave back in 2011. I'd argue it still holds today; maybe even more so, given the recent shift back to C++ from Microsoft. I'm not sure how much additional support for win8 there is in MFC, but if you're not fully switching to Metro (which I imagine you won't; if you have a 'product' you'll need to support older Windows for at least, what, 5 years?), it doesn't matter all that much.

I have yet to see a .Net/WPF application that feels as 'solid' as a C++ one (yes I realize those are technically orthogonal, but really, who builds .Net UI's in C++?). I understand why people want to move away from MFC; it's not like I don't understand its negative sides. IMO, what it comes down to is: how much value do you place on rapid development? For some applications (line of business, products with a short lifespan), time to market and speed of making changes is more important than being 'solidly' engineered. For other (professional tools, systems software), creating solid software with a great user experience is more important. I have yet to be shown production software (as opposed to 'tech demos') that do that in the more 'modern' frameworks; MFC (or maybe I should say 'win api used through C++', but MFC in that respect has enough going for it for the positives to trump the negatives) applications are (still) (often) the best tool for that. IMO.

One last thing to consider though is your devs. If they've been programming MFC for 15 years, they are likely programming their careers into a corner. If you insist on continuing to use MFC, you may alienate them. You'll have to weigh the business risks in that versus the technical considerations (I'm taking from your question that you are a business owner). Feel free to contact me for followup discussion if you'd prefer to do so privately.

Comment: There are quite a few WPF applications (or at least heavily leveraged with WPF) that I would consider "solid", including Visual Studio.

Comment: @Roel -- First, I appreciate this discussion (and read through your answer from 2011).  It's not subjective when experts are citing their real-world experiences with development tools/technologies.

Comment: @Roel -- First, I appreciate this discussion (and read through your answer from 2011).  It's not subjective when experts are citing their real-world experiences with development tools/technologies.

Like so many others it has been frustrating to realize, through 30 years of development, that what Microsoft SAYS and DOES are often two different things.

What might be helpful would be a RAD tool that generated and managed MFC -- as a tool that could help rough out the overall structure.

Comment: @Roel -- Finally -- on the subject of devs: I am a business owner, but I also program (C++) and have learned the hard lesson of allowing engineers to make strategic business decisions: more often than not an engineer will want to work with new, different, and/or exciting technologies -- it's human nature and they have to focus on their careers and not on how to best maintain code 10 years into the future...

Comment: @ Reed Copsey - I didn't want to name names, but I'd consider Visual Studio an example of a very non-solid piece of software. My customers would balk if we delivered that sort of quality, and that rapid a pace of hardware/OS upgrades. And imagine that MS has all the people, money and time to get the best out of WPF (and the people who build it in the next building), and still VS is the best they can do? Then what chance do we mere mortals have? But again, it's a question of who the audience is, and I guess that MS decided developers could swallow it.

Comment: @SMGreenfield - we're in the same boat then. And like many devs, I too once upon a time was eager to get away from MFC as fast as possible. I/we tried various alternatives and found out the hard way that the grass isn't always greener. Re: the devs, I can't blame them, and I understand - if it weren't for some weird turns of events years ago I'd be just like that. It's just one of those things that people who will have to face the consequences of bad choices 10 years from now.

Comment: @Roel I don't see anything wrong with a solid native feeling UI built in C# .NET (WinForms not WFP) with calls to native C++ libraries where required. Most .NET WinForms UI components use underlying native Win32 controls & windows and render with the same visual styles and effects unlike WPF and MFC (some MFC UI elements are non-native and hideous).

Comment: @Kurian I don't see anything wrong with such a UI either. The thing is that until proven otherwise, I am skeptical of the average (even above-average) developer being able to produce such a thing using WinForms (apart from the fact that WinForms is mostly abandoned by MS and a dying technology). Even if most components are thin wrappers around win32, why do so many .Net/WinForms/WPF desktop apps feel so sluggish, have so many redrawing issues, are so poorly developed all together? Again, I'm not saying it's impossible to make quality apps with it, just that I don't see many people doing it.

Comment: @Roel Media Player Classic Home Cinema is a fine example.

Answer (score 1):

A really easily said solution would be to port the entire C++ code over to .NET's C# or C++/CLI and then interface it with WPF. This can be complicated, but, you enjoy the ease of coding entirely in .NET (3.5 SP1 and Visual Studio 2010 preferrable).

You can also interface existing code to .NET to use WPF through COM Interop. COM Interop essentially registers a .NET component as a COM component in a system. When it is invoked, the CLR performs the code execution and marshalling for your program to call into (More info - msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(v=vs.80).aspx).

The final method is to dump MFC and call straight into the Windows (Win32) API. Windows API can be easier to use from within your code than the other methods. In modern Windows API, GDI+ (Graphics Device Interface) is implemented atop DirectX (DWM and DXGI) and can be easily extended through COM and is a somewhat viable alternative to WPF and Modern UI.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody should create new project based on MFC and Win32. Windows Mordern UI and unified API is the future. I don't think .Net is the answer for every application, especially for projects that have large amount of C++ native code. 
We know that Microsoft is working on the unified API. I hope that is the answer to this question.

Comment: "We know that Microsoft is working on the unified API." -> Why not wait on the unified API, then?